# How to modify node element with boost::property_tree and put_value(const Type &value)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I am fairly new to `boost::property_tree` and I am having a little trouble with what should be a simple task.

I have a default xml file of which is to be copied and made unique with parameters passed into via the `ptree & modelModifier(...)` function below. All I want to do is parse the xml into a ptree, and then modify the `name` field (amongst others, but lets just start with `name`) from "default" to whatever name is passed in from the `object_name` variable, then write that back into the original ptree.

The function `pTreeIterator` just iterates through each child and displays its contents.

**xml**

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.7'>
  <model name='default'>
    <link name='link'>
      <inertial>
        <mass>3.14999</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>2.86712</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>2.86712</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.524998</izz>
        </inertia>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      </inertial>
    </link>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

**Code**

```c++
void ptreeIterator(ptree & pt)
{
    using boost::property_tree::ptree;
    for (auto&it : pt)
    {
        std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "------------------------------------------------------" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Iteration output: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "1: pt1: " << it.first << std::endl;

        if(pt.get_child_optional(it.first))
        {
            cout << "pt.get_child_optional(it.first) ---> " << it.first << endl;
            ptree pt2 = pt.get_child(it.first);
            for (auto&it2 : pt2)
            {
                std::cout << "\t2: " << "pt2: " << it2.first << " :: " << (std::string)it2.second.data() << std::endl;
                if(pt2.get_child_optional(it2.first))
                {
                    ptree pt3 = pt2.get_child(it2.first);
                    for (auto&it3 : pt3)
                    {
                        std::cout << "\t\t3: " << "pt3: " << it3.first << " :: " << (std::string)it3.second.data() << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

ptree & modelModifier(ptree &model, double px, double py, std::string object_name, uint16_t height)
{
    for(auto &it:model){
        cout << "it.first = " << it.first << endl;
        if(it.first=="model"){
            cout << "MODEL TAG" << endl;
            model.put_value(object_name);
        }
        ptreeIterator(model);
    }

}

int main(){
    ptree ptModel;

    const string filenameToInsert = "model.sdf";
    
    std::ifstream ifsModel(filenameToInsert,std::ifstream::binary);

    read_xml(ifsModel, ptModel, boost::property_tree::xml_parser::trim_whitespace);         

    modelModifier(ptModel, 0, 0, "TEST1234567", 30);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
it.first = model
it.second.data() 
ptreeIterator
------------------------------------------------------
Iteration output: 
1: pt1: model
pt.get_child_optional(it.first) ---> model
        2: pt2: <xmlattr> :: 
                3: pt3: name :: default
```

**Expected Output**

```
it.first = model
it.second.data() 
ptreeIterator
------------------------------------------------------
Iteration output: 
1: pt1: model
pt.get_child_optional(it.first) ---> model
        2: pt2: <xmlattr> :: 
                3: pt3: name :: TEST1234567
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your code has [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), since `modelModifier` doesn't return a value.

The C-style cast in `(std::string)it2.second.data()` is extremely dangerous as it risks `reinterpret_cast`-ing unrelated types. There is no reason whatsoever for this kind of blunt casting. Just remove the cast!

Also, `ptreeIterator` should probably take a `ptree const&`, not `ptree&`.

With these fixed, the sample does NOT show the output you claim, instead it prints (**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/771ecd3771678555)**)

```
it.first = sdf
ptreeIterator
------------------------------------------------------
Iteration output:
1: pt1: sdf
pt.get_child_optional(it.first) ---> sdf
        2: pt2: <xmlattr> ::
                3: pt3: version :: 1.7
        2: pt2: model ::
                3: pt3: <xmlattr> ::
                3: pt3: link ::
```

Now even in your question output, you clearly see the difference between the `model` node and its name attribute, which apparently you want to modify. Just write the code to access that:

```
it.second.get_child("<xmlattr>.name").put_value(object_name);
```

> This would be correct, assuming that the attribute always exists and instead of `ptModel` you pass `ptModel.get_child("sdf")` to `modifyModel`).

### Other Notes: SIMPLIFY!

That said, please simplify the whole thing!

```
  ptree pt2 = pt.get_child(it.first);
```

Should have been something like

```
  ptree const& pt2 = it.second;
```

And

- the use of `get_child_optional` only to repeat with `get_child` is even more wasteful
- Good practice is to separate output/query and mutation. So don't call `ptreeIterator` from inside `modelModifier`
- Also, give functions a good descriptive name (so that you don't have sheepishly explain "The function `pTreeIterator` just iterates through each child and displays its contents" - just call it `displayModel`?)
- Instead of painstakingly (and flawed) iterating the particular model and printing it in pretty confusing bespoke manner, just use `write_xml`/`write_info`/`write_json` to dump it in a reliable manner.

### Listing

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5380164e90f84e4f)**

```
namespace Model {
    void display(ptree const& pt)
    {
        write_json(std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "\n---------------\n", pt);
    }

    void modify(ptree& model, double, double, std::string object_name, uint16_t)
    {
        for (auto& it : model) {
            std::cout << "root = " << it.first << std::endl;
            it.second.get_child("model.<xmlattr>.name").put_value(object_name);
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
root = sdf
display
---------------
{
    "sdf": {
        "<xmlattr>": {
            "version": "1.7"
        },
        "model": {
            "<xmlattr>": {
                "name": "TEST1234567"
            },
            "link": {
                "<xmlattr>": {
                    "name": "link"
                },
                "inertial": {
                    "mass": "3.14999",
                    "inertia": {
                        "ixx": "2.86712",
                        "ixy": "0",
                        "ixz": "0",
                        "iyy": "2.86712",
                        "iyz": "0",
                        "izz": "0.524998"
                    },
                    "pose": "0 0 0 0 -0 0"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Bonus

In the case that the name attribute might not already exist, the following code would create it on the fly:

```
void modify(ptree& model, double, double, std::string object_name, uint16_t)
{
    ptree value;
    value.put_value(object_name);
    for (auto& it : model) {
        std::cout << "root = " << it.first << std::endl;
        it.second.put_child("model.<xmlattr>.name", value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @sehe! Appreciate the time you took for this, it has cleared up quite a lot.